# MySQL Always Getting "Out of Memory Exception" when executing this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the exception "Out of Memory" and I have ran out of ideas about how to do it.

I have the following tables :

```
create table CGNS
(
CHANNEL SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PNL_DATE     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
CHANNEL_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_LINE  CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_LINE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT NUMERIC(20, 6) NOT NULL
)

create table CP
(
MARKETPLACE_ID NUMERIC(38, 0) NOT NULL,
CHANNEL     SMALLINT NOT NULL,
SHIP_MONTH  DATE NOT NULL,
GL_PRODUCT_GROUP NUMERIC(4, 0) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_CATEGORY VARCHAR(100) NULL,
PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY VARCHAR(100) NULL,
PRIME_PLAN  CHAR(10) NULL,
ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR(10) NULL,
CP_COMPONENT  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT  NUMERIC(20, 6) NOT NULL
)

create table ACCOUNT_MAPPER
(
CGNS_ACCOUNT   CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
CP_COMPONENT   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

create table CHANNEL_MAPPER
(
CGNS_CHANNEL   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CP_MARKETPLACE_ID  NUMERIC(38, 0) NOT NULL,
CP_CHANNEL  SMALLINT NOT NULL   
)

Create table PRODUCT_LINE_MAPPER
(
CGNS_PRODUCT_LINE   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CP_GL_PRODUCT_GROUP NUMERIC(4, 0) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to use the following query to generate data into table SLICED as below :

```
INSERT INTO SLICED

SELECT      CGNS.CHANNEL,              

            CGNS.PRODUCT_LINE,
            CGNS.ACCOUNT,
            CP.PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
            CP.PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,  
            CP.ITEM_SIZE,
            CP.PRIME_PLAN,
            CGNS.PNL_DATE,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 

            CASE 
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN NULL
                ELSE ((CP.AMOUNT / CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT) * CGNS.AMOUNT)
                             END,

            CASE 
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN ((CP.AMOUNT / CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT) * CGNS.AMOUNT) 
                ELSE NULL
                    END,

            CGNS.CURRENCY_CODE,
            'Method',

            CASE -- DRIVER AMOUNT
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN NULL
                ELSE CP.AMOUNT
            END,


            CASE  -- DRIVER QTY TO DO
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN CP.AMOUNT
                ELSE NULL
            END,

            CP.CURRENCY_CODE

FROM CGNS

JOIN ChannelMapper
            ON CGNS.CHANNEL = ChannelMapper.CGNS_CHANNEL

JOIN  AccountMapper
            ON AccountMapper.CGNS_ACCOUNT = CGNS.ACCOUNT


JOIN  PLMapper
            ON PLMapper.CGNS_PRODUCT_LINE = CGNS.PRODUCT_LINE

JOIN  CP
            ON (
                            ChannelMapper.CP_MARKETPLACE_ID = CP.MARKETPLACE_ID
                            AND ChannelMapper.CP_CHANNEL = CP.CHANNEL
                            AND AccountMapper.CP_COMPONENT = CP.CP_COMPONENT
                            AND PLMapper.CP_GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = CP.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP

               )

JOIN   (SELECT CP_COMPONENT, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT FROM AUTO_PNL_CP GROUP BY CP_COMPONENT) as CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS
            ON CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.CP_COMPONENT = CP.CP_COMPONENT
```

HERE is what the Explain Plan (Query Execution Plan) looks like :

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1  |  PRIMARY    |  NULL | NULL |  NULL         | NULL|  NULL   | NULL| NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables


2  | DERIVED     |  NULL | NULL | NULL          | NULL|  NULL   | NULL| NULL | no matching row in const table
```

Comment: Your query got cut off. And the execution plan is unreadable as a graphic, please paste it in as text.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I've pasted the execution plan as text. Thanks,

Comment: The end of the query is still missing. It ends in the middle of a subquery.